# wxWidgets - terminate called without an active exception (using std::thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, wxwidgets

I am writing GUI application which use my own library which is based on `boost::asio` an C++11 standard library. This is implementation of `gui_client::OnInit` and `gui_client::OnExit` methods of class `gui_client` which derives from `wxApp`:

```
bool gui_client::OnInit()
{
    io_service_ = new boost::asio::io_service;
    client_ = new client(*io_service_);
    frame = new main_frame();

    std::thread reader([this]() {
        // thread code
    });

    reader_thread = &reader;

    frame->Show();
    Debug("Returning OnInit");
    return true;
}

int gui_client::OnExit()
{
    reader_thread->join();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles and application starts. I see debug information in command line ('Returning OnInit') and then:

> terminate called without an active exception

I tried to set breakpoints in `gdb` on some `wxApp` functions, but I cannot find the place where error is returned. `gui_client` class has only three methods:

- `virtual bool OnInit()`
- `virtual int OnExit()`
- `client * get_client()`

When I do not start reader thread (`std::thread reader`) everything works well. When I started thread with empty loop in lambda function I got error which I mentioned above. I'm also sure that thread code is correct because the same code works well in CLI testing application.

I use `wxWidgets 3.0.1.0` and `g++ 4.7.2` (Debian). I use this g++ command for comilation:

```
g++ `wx-config --version=3.0 --cxxflags` -std=c++11 -I./headers -I../headers -L../lib/Debug -DDEBUG -g -c -o [obj_file] [source]
```

and this command for linking:

```
g++ `wx-config --version=3.0 --cxxflags` -std=c++11 -I./headers -I../headers -L../lib/Debug -DDEBUG -g [obj_files] -ltamandua `wx-config --version=3.0 --libs` -lboost_system -pthread -o [output]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
std::thread reader([this]() {
    // thread code
});

reader_thread = &reader;
```

`reader` will be destroyed after `OnInit` function ends (and terminate will be called, since `thread` is joinable). You should use smart-pointer in class in this case, or create `reader_thread` using `new`, or simply save thread in object and assign it to your `reader_thread` (reader_thread should be object, not pointer) via move.

1) `reader_thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>([this]() {});`

2) `reader_thread = new std::thread([this]() {});`

3)

```
std::thread reader([this](){});
reader_thread = std::move(reader);
```

Comment: @Griwes it will be moved too. Just without named variable `reader`, but move-assignment operator will be called.

Comment: Thank you for help! What a stupid mistake... and simple solution.

Comment: @ForEveR, of course. Yet, my way is one non-temporary and one line shorter, and it is immediately obvious what it does (while with yours it takes slightly more time to get what this does).